How to built up a kd-tree?
i am trying to wrap my head around KD-trees at the moment and wanted to ask if anybody has any good resources about them (videos, papers, etc.).
I made an exercise example for myself, but I'm not sure if I got it correctly. Maybe one of you could look over it.
So, I made 6 points:

(30,40)
(5,25)
(10,12)
(70,70)
(50,30)
(35,45)

kd-tree solution attempt
Attempting to solve my example.

Can you share why the code posted on wikipedia about KD-trees did not help you in solving your problem?   ( Given a list of n points, the following algorithm uses a median-finding sort to construct a balanced k-d tree containing those points. )
